# Validating NPM Package Integrity

Tags: windows-10, checksum, npm

I'm being tasked to validate the integrity of my downloads from npm by our IT/Security department. I'm a programmer and while I understand at a top level what performing a sha checksum is, I'm having trouble figuring out how to do that on my NPM packages.

I successfully performed a check on a single file download from the browser for something other than npm. NPM installs come with an "integrity" value in the "package-lock.json", but I am unsure how to use that value. For example when trying to perform this check on the D3 library which has the "integrity" value of "sha512-4PL5hHaHwX4m7Zr1UapXW23apo6pexCgdetdJ5kTmADpG/7T9Gkxw0M0tf/pjoB63ezCCm0u5UaFYy2aMt0Mcw==" I have been unable to recreate that value. I tried to create a tarball of the package folder using 7zip, and I even tried directly downloading the ".tgz" file from the "resolved" value "https://registry.npmjs.org/d3/-/d3-5.16.0.tgz" which still does not yield the right checksum.

I have used both of the following commands which both give me the same result. (e0f2f9847687c17e26ed9af551aa575b6ddaa68ea97b10a075eb5d2799139800e91bfed3f46931c34334b5ffe98e807addecc20a6d2ee54685632d9a32dd0c73)

```
Get-FileHash -Path C:\Path\to\d3-5.16.0.tgz -Algorithm SHA512
certutil -hashfile C:\Path\to\d3-5.16.0.tgz sha512
```

If anyone can walk me through what I'm doing wrong or missing it would be very appreciated.

Comment: Start by reading [Subresource Integrity](https://w3c.github.io/webappsec-subresource-integrity/#the-integrity-attribute). If you can make sense of it then good luck :)

Comment: Yeah. I already found that. I am not competent enough in this area for that to be of use and even if I was, it doesn't look like it would help with my NPM specific question.

Comment: The docs may help https://docs.npmjs.com/verifying-the-pgp-signature-for-a-package-from-the-npm-public-registry

Comment: Yes I found that too, that is PGP validation which is good but not what I have been tasked to do.

Comment: I suspect your question is more suited to [so] ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Validation depends on the type of file per https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v6/configuring-npm/package-lock-json#integrity

> integrity
>
> This is a Standard Subresource Integrity for this resource.
>
> For bundled dependencies this is not included, regardless of source.
>
> For registry sources, this is the integrity that the registry
> provided, or if one wasn't provided the SHA1 in shasum.
>
> For git sources this is the specific commit hash we cloned from.
>
> For remote tarball sources this is an integrity based on a SHA512 of the file.
>
> For local tarball sources: This is an integrity field based on the
> SHA512 of the file.

To calculate for a tgz, https://w3c.github.io/webappsec-subresource-integrity/ provides an example which you can adapt - so you can check it like this:

```
curl -LO <someurl>/some-package-1.0.0.tgz
cat ./some-package-1.0.0.tgz | openssl dgst -sha512 -binary | openssl base64 -A
```